# C++ std::map key sort comparison function?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have a class where I overload all the comparison operators. I load a bunch of these objects into a map as keys and I expect the map to sort them least to greatest.

However, the map is actually sorted by greatest to least. Why is this? Does it not use the comparison operators on the key when it sorts the map? How can I make it do this?

Comment: Please post the code, It is impossible to answer without seeing the code.

Comment: `std::map` by default does use `operator<`.  Are you sure your implementation of `operator<` isn't backwards?

Comment: How are you checking the ordering? Can you check the expected ordering by hand, e.g. `cout << obj1 << " < " << obj2 << " is " << boolalpha << (obj1 < obj2) << endl;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the definition for std::map, the 3rd parameter is the comparator - `std::less< Key >` by default. The default implementation of which is just to invoke `operator<`.

You could try defining a new version in the header where `YourType` is defined, like so:

```
template<> std::less< YourType >
{
    bool operator()(
        const YourType& lhs,
        const YourType& rhs)
    {
        if(!(lhs.member1 < rhs.member1))
        {
           return false;
        }

        if(!(lhs.member2 < rhs.member2))
        {
           return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Remember to friend `std::less< YourType >` in your class.

The actual test must comply with the following or you'll get all kinds of problems:

- lhs < rhs = true
- rha < lhs = false
- lhs < lhs = false

One important thing to note (that I discovered quite recently) is that if your compiler starts complaining that you've redefined the meaning of `std::less` or other funky things, it could be that you've only forward declared your `YourType` when you declared your `std::map< YourType >`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You should post your code that implements the overload of the comparison operators, so may answer is based on guessing:

Your problem could be a simple typo (I did that once)

```
bool operator < ( T lhs, T rhs ) const
{
    return rhs < lhs; // note: lhs is on the right!
}
```

but actually you want:

```
bool operator < ( T lhs, T rhs ) const
{
    return lhs < rhs; 
}
```