# Comparison implementation C++ map incomplete type not allowed

Tags: c++, dictionary, ramcloud

I'm trying to implement a custom C++ comparison function, to be passed to a `std::map`. 
Following the instructions in the `map` API, I implemented:

```
 35 typedef std::pair<uint64_t, KeyHash> TabletKey;
 36 
 37 class CmpTabletKey {
 38     public:
 39         bool operator()(const TabletKey& key1, const TabletKey& key2) const {
 40             if (!(key1.first < key2.first)) {
 41                 return false;
 42             }
 43             if (!(key2.first < key1.first)) {
 44                 return false;
 45             }
 46 
 47             return true;
 48         }
 49 };
```

Inside the class where the `map` is a property, I have:

```
 55 class ObjectFinder {
 56   public:
 57     class TableConfigFetcher; // forward declaration, see full declaration below
 58     class CmpTabletKey;
        // .. more code here
      private:
 97     std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet, CmpTabletKey> tableMap;
     }
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
/home/ribeiro.phillipe/ramcloud/src/ObjectFinder.h:97:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhatlinux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:453: 
error: incomplete type ‘RAMCloud::ObjectFinder::CmpTabletKey’ not allowed
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/map:60,
```

I don't know why is that happening. Also, I would be open to use the `std::less` implementatation [less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680076/c-stdmap-key-sort-comparison-function)

Comment: You cannot use a forward declaration to instantiate an `std::map`. In general, standard library containers need complete types for instantiation.

Comment: @juanchopanza could you give me an example how is it done?

Comment: Just make sure the definition of `CmpTabletKey` is available before you instantiate the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring a second `CmpTabletKey` inside the class
`ObjectFinder`; when instantiating the map, you're inside the
class, so this is the one the compiler finds.  Just drop the
`class CmpTabletKey;` statement inside the class (or change it
to a typedef to `::CmpTabletKey`, or move the entire definition
of `CmpTabletKey` inside the class `ObjectFinder`.

Also, you're comparison function looks a bit strange.  It looks
to me that it can only return `true` if the keys are equal,
which doesn't define an ordering relationship.  If you just want
to compare the first field:

```
bool operator()( TabletKey const& lhs, TabletKey const& rhs ) const
{
    return lhs.first < rhs.first;
}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Typically types that are passed as template parameters to a standard library template have to be fully defined when the template is instantiated. (Exceptions are smart pointer templates)
This applies also to the comparator for `std::map`, so **the forward declaration is not enough**, you have to provide the complete definition of `CmpTabletKey` to define your

```
std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet, CmpTabletKey> tableMap;
                                             //^^^------- needs full definition
```

Comment: totally agree, but where do I place `CmpTabletKey` inside the class `ObjectFinder`? I implemented it above of the `ObjectFinder` class declaration

Comment: @philippe But you declared a new one nested in the class `ObjectFinder`, and that's the one which is incomplete.

Comment: @philippe if you defined it outside the class, you don't need a declaration inside the class.